# Calculate Level 2 page table bits and page table entries for each

Tags: virtual-address-space, page-tables

1. Level 1 page table occupies exactly one page of memory
2. 32 bit virtual address
3. Page size 8kb
4. PTE 4 bytes

How many bits for each of the fields?
 
How many entries are in the level 1 table?
How many entries are in the level 2 table? 
How many pages do the level 2 page table map?

I tried and got 13 for offset and 11 for level 1 and 8 for level 2. Not sure how to solve the rest.

Answer (score 0):

- Since the level 1 page table is one page in size, that means there are `8k / 4 -> 2k` or `2^11` entries in the level 1 page table.  This matches with your offset above.
- Since there are `2^32 / 2^13 -> 2^19` total pages, then there must be `2^19` level 2 page entries if all pages are mapped.
- Each entry in the level 1 page table points to a level 2 page table "page" which has `2^19 / 2^11` or `2^8` or 256 entries.  Again, this matches with your answer above.